# Is there a Clojure convention for naming private functions?

Tags: clojure, naming-conventions

When I define a private function in Clojure, I usually use a `-` prefix as a visual indicator that the function cannot be used outside of my namespace, e.g.

```
(defn- -name []
  (let [formatter (formatter "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSSS")]
    (format "fixjure-%s" (unparse formatter (now)))))
```

But the `-` prefix seems to also be a convention for public methods when using `gen-class`.

Is there any generally accepted convention for `defn-`'d functions in the Clojure community, or should I simply use non-prefixed names?

It seems that lots of code in clojure.contrib (may it rest in peace) uses normal names for private functions, so maybe that is best, but I really like the visual indicator--maybe my C / Perl background is just too strong! ;)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There's not a convention; the visual indicator is prevalent in languages with no built-in notion of private functions. Since Clojure's functions defined with `defn-` are not visible outside their namespace, there is no need to prefix functions with an uglifier ;)

So do what you but, but you should probably want to just do as the rest of community does and just name them normally! It'll make your life easier.

Comment: What a beautiful language design!

Answer (score 25):

I am unaware of any naming conventions but you can attach `^:private` metadata tag for defining private functions. This is exactly equivalent to `defn-`, but is a  little clearer, IMHO.

```
(defn ^:private foo [])
```

Comment: And to do this for the current namespace: `(def ^:private -ns- *ns*)`