# How can I just public expose some functions of my namespace in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I have the following code:

```
(ns mylib-clojure.core)

(defn foo2 [x]
  (inc x))

(defn foo1 [x]
  (foo2 x))
```

Function `foo2` is just used internally inside `foo1`. Let's say I don't want to expose function `foo2` so I have a smaller API provided for users of my namespace. Is it possible to make `foo2` "private"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare foo2 as ["private"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846423/is-there-a-clojure-convention-for-naming-private-functions):

```
(defn- foo2 [x] (inc x))
```

It will be not visible outside `mylib-clojure.core`. Documentation of `defn-` can be found [here](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/defn-). Another option is to declare it inside `foo1`:

```
(defn foo1 [x]
  (let [foo2 (fn [x] (inc x))]
    (foo2 x)))
```

Comment: this hifen after defn makes it private? This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: It is probably worth noting that your functions marked as private can still be accessed by fully qualifying the function. Unlike private in Java, private in clojure iis more like an agreement i.e. Please don't use this directly, but just in case you do need it and you know what your doing you can.

Comment: @TimX It's not entirely true. Just referring to "private" function `bar` results in `CompilerException java.lang.IllegalStateException: var: #'a/bar is not public`. Maybe there is some hacky way to retrieve it, but at the same time in Java you can use Reflections to call private methods. The point is that these private constructs do not prohibit usage outside of scope in principle - it's rather normal usage boundary.

Comment: @Jarlax It isn't that hacky - just fully qualify it i.e. (#'a/bar).  You can even do (def bar #'a/bar) and then just call (bar). While you may be able to access private functions in Java using reflections api, it is much more hacky than just fully qualifying the name.